# TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: webpack

I tried updating my project to the latest vue and webpack but whenever I try to run my app with `npm run dev` it gives me an error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'E:\repos\project\build\webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor
```

I'm using the latest webpack, and webpack-cli:

```
"webpack": "^5.35.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
```

And also my scripts are updated from `webpack-dev-serve` to `webpack serve` as shows:

```
"dev:eih": "npm run generate-assets:test:eih && cross-env TARGET_BRAND=eih cross-env NODE_ENV=development cross-env PROJECT_VERBOSE_LOG=true cross-env PROJECT_MPIN_IN_BROWSER=true webpack serve --config ./build/webpack.config.js",
```

I could not fin any answer which helped

Answer (score 6):

config.plugins

```
plugins: [
  - new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
]
```

config.optimization

```
+ optimization: {
   moduleIds: 'named'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [it isn't needed anymore](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11637#issuecomment-706718119) has optimizations are already done out of the box.

[Although someone suggested](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11637#issuecomment-706708772) replacing it with

```
optimization: {
   moduleIds: 'named'
}
```