# Getting Webpack TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to compile a react app using `yarn test:build` but i am getting the following error as below

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.NamedChunksPlugin is not a constructor

**node version :14.5.1**
**package.json**
    "wdio-image-comparison-service": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.9.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-stats-plugin": "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11637 seems like some quick googling could've helped here. This is a github issue on the webpack repo with your exact error message, including a link on how to update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381359/typeerror-webpack-namedmodulesplugin-is-not-a-constructor